# scrlttr2 no firsthead

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I am currently writing a job application using the scrlttr2 package. I am sending the application as a pdf file, so I really don't need the `\firsthead`, so I emptied it by using `\firsthead{}`. However, there is still a lot of blank space above the backadress. I know that this is needed for letters which are actually printed out and mailed, but since I am not mailing this letter I would like to remove that extra space. Is that possible using something like KOMAoptions or am I using the wrong `\documentclass`?

Comment: Can you please give a little, yet complete, mock-up document with the relevant settings, so we don't have to start from zero?

Answer (score 1):

Best use

```
\KOMAoptions{firsthead=false}
```